# how to combine each RGB pixel into a single hypercomplex number?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, compression, octave

I am new to MatLab and its toolboxes. I am trying to implement a method mentioned in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6738907).

It is mentioned to combine each RGB pixel of the image into a hypercomplex form which consists of one real part and three imaginary parts (i, j, and k).

I've been trying and searching for too long in order to find a solution on how to represent each RGB pixel into a hypercomplex form in MatLab. It would use this Hypercomplex representation in order to apply QFT (Quaternion Fourier Transform).

I would be glad if anyone could help me.

Comment: Step 1: find an implementation of the QFT. Step 2: find out what input representation that function expects. MATLAB doesn’t do quaternions natively, and there are many different ways you could conceivably represent them.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend.

From: https://books.google.de/books?id=WR5tAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA110&ots=DpUyuah5XE&dq=hypercomplex%20rgb%20conversion&hl=de&pg=PA112#v=onepage&q=hypercomplex%20rgb%20conversion&f=false

```
%requires the open-source quaternion toolbox
%Read the input colour RGB (3-channel) n x n x 3 pixels square image
I = imread('input_colour_image.tif');
% Encode RGB image in the three imaginary parts of a quaternion
qI = convert(quaternion(I(:,:,1),I(:,:,2),I(:,:,3)),'double')./256;
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work, and I followed all the steps mentioned in the code in the book. but anyways, I found my solution to this problem. Thanks for your help!